# File not working offline (React-Native)

Tags: react-native

I have a video on my app built with create-react-native-app and I'm using the Video component of expo.io . I am displaying a local video, and on my application this is working when connected to the internet, but when the app is offline the video does not play/work/load.

Here is my project structure:

```
App.js          app.json        node_modules        yarn.lock
App.test.js     images          package.json
README.md       my-app-key.keystore videos
```

Here is the code for the video player component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Video } from 'expo';

class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
     <Video
      source={require('./videos/asthma-1.mp4')} //local video
      rate={1.0}
      volume={1.0}
      muted={false}
      useNativeControls
      resizeMode="cover"
      shouldPlay
      isLooping
      style={{ width: 900, height: 450, position:'relative',left:350,bottom:410 }} />
      )
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the video being delivered online but not offline?

I am using it on an android device btw

Edit: Also, I noticed that the images located in the image folder work both offline and online. Did I structure/name my videos folder incorrectly for that not to load offline?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be related to this [request of standalone app](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/allow-standalone-apps-to-load-and-function-with-no-internet-connection)

This feature should be live in expo in the next release (21.0 or more)

Comment: So this is an expo issue and not a react native issue? Do you know when expo plans to release v21.0? Also, what do you suggest as for playing the videos offline

Comment: Expo is releasing a new SDK approximatively every month, you should subscribe to the canny website, to get all futur updates.